# QImage::Format_mono to .png and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qimage

I have created a `QImage` of format `QImage::Format_Mono`. When I try and display the image to a `QGraphicsView` through a `QGraphicsScene` the view is unchanged. The `QImage` is loaded to the scene using a `QPixmap` produced through the `QPixmap::fromImage()` function. I also tried saving the `QPixmap` as a PNG/JPG/BMP using the save function as well to no avail. The basic code structure is as follows:

```
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
view.setScene(scene);
QImage img(size,QImage::Format_Mono);
QVector<QRgb> v;
v.append(Qt::color0); // I have tried using black and white 
v.append(Qt::color1); // instead of color0 and 1 as well.
img.setColorTable(v);
// Do some stuff to populate the image using img.setPixel(c,r,bw)
// where bw is an index either 0 or 1 and c and r are within bounds
QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
p.save("mono.png");
scene->addPixmap(p);
// Code to display the view
```

If I instead make the image of `QImage::Format_RGB888` and fill the pixels with either black or white the PNG/View displays appropriately.

How can I update my code to display the `QImage` in a `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: By the way, I guess `view.setScene(scene);` was just a typo in SO, not in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that the `Qt::GlobalColor`s (such as `Qt::white` or `Qt::color0`) are of type `QColor`, and not `QRgb` as expected. (`QRgb` is a typedef for unsigned int)

You can convert a `QColor` to a `QRgb` by using the method `QColor::rgb()`, or directly create a `QRgb` using the global method `qRgb(r,g,b)`. Following is a complete working example to illustrate, that displays (and saves as PNG) the very exact image whether `mono` is `true` or `false`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    view->setScene(scene);

    int W = 100;
    int H = 100;
    QImage img;
    uint color0 = qRgb(255,0,0);
    uint color1 = Qt::green.rgb();
    bool mono = true;
    if(mono)
    {
        img = QImage(QSize(W,H),QImage::Format_Mono);
        QVector<QRgb> v; v << color0 << color1;
        img.setColorTable(v);
        for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<H; j++)
        {
            uint index;
            if(j-(j/10)*10 > 5)
                index = 0;
            else
                index = 1;
            img.setPixel(i,j,index);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        img = QImage(QSize(W,H),QImage::Format_RGB888);
        for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<H; j++)
        {
            uint color;
            if(j-(j/10)*10 > 5)
                color = color0;
            else
                color = color1;
            img.setPixel(i,j,color);
        }
    }

    QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    p.save("mono.png");
    scene->addPixmap(p);
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You were right. I found the issue to be that I was using Qt global colors i.e. `Qt::white` and `Qt::color0`. I had to convert these values using `QColor(Qt::white).rgb()` for it to behave as expected.